# Payara 5.194 server is not automatically cleaning up the Payara logs

Tags: payara

Multiple web application deployed on payara server and running as a windows services configured, the windows configuration xml file include --watchdog and log rotation in domain.xml is set to `log-rotation-limit-in-bytes="2000000`, logging properties `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=10`, once it reaches the threshold it throws the 'COULD NOT DELETE LOG FILE.'

> [2020-10-20T17:13:26.634+0530] [Payara 5.194] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=GFFileHandler log pump] [timeMillis: 1603194206634] [levelValue: 1000] [[
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete log file: D:\Tools\server\Webapps\logs\server.log.lck
> at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.cleanUpHistoryLogFiles(GFFileHandler.java:827)
> at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.lambda$rotate$2(GFFileHandler.java:905)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotate(GFFileHandler.java:845)
> at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.log(GFFileHandler.java:967)
> at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler$1.run(GFFileHandler.java:581)
> ]]

Found the similar behavior observed in glassfish gitbub link https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/21275 but no proper solution.

Any suggestion on this?

PS:: Found the similar issue when just running the payara server with asadmin command "start-domain --verbose --debug --domainDir webApps"

Comment: It's best to raise this as an issue on Payara github: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues and provide all the info there. If it can be reproduced and it's really a defect, the Payara team may be eventually able to fix it.

Comment: Thanks OndroMih for you suggestion, created in github https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4960